# How to make Mapbox load on gatsby site? Build succeeds but map not displaying, despite working in dev mode

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mapbox, gatsby

I'm trying to use a Mapbox map on a gatsby website. I used the code from their react Mapbox tutorial: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/use-mapbox-gl-js-with-react/ and put it into a map component.

I call the map component on the footer and it works perfectly during development mode, but when I run `gatsby build` and then `gatsby serve` it refuses to show the map despite showing the container :

https://postimg.cc/mPcRfYhV

I've tried the other suggestion which is from the docs too, that is to use in gatsby-node.js

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /@mapbox|mapbox-gl/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

for the test property I've tried using `/mapbox|@mapbox|mapbox-gl|mapboxgl/` but nothing seems to make it work like it does in dev mode.

any ideas?

The component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";

const styles = {
  width: "220px",
  height: '130px',
  margin: '2em 0'
};


const Map = () => {


  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const mapContainer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {

    mapboxgl.accessToken = process.env.MY_KEY
    const initializeMap = ({ setMap, mapContainer }) => {
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer.current,
        style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11", 
        center: [-6.2603, 53.3498],
        zoom: 9
      });

      map.on("load", () => {
        setMap(map);
        map.resize();
      });
       new mapboxgl.Marker({color:'#1E3873'}).setLngLat([-6.2603, 53.3498]).addTo(map)

    };

    if (!map) initializeMap({ setMap, mapContainer });
  }, [map]);


  return <div ref={el => (mapContainer.current = el)} style={styles} />;



};

export default Map;
```

The Map component is called on the footer component in a normal way by just importing the component and using `<Map />`.

Picture of it working fine when using `gatsby develop`

[image: Screenshot-2020-12-21-at-20-52-33.png]

Picture of it not working when using `gatsby build` `gatsby serve`

[image: Screenshot-2020-12-21-at-11-58-19.png]

SOLUTION EDIT: for some reason mapbox-gl 2.0 doesn't work, or I can't get it to work. Someone else had the same issue and suggested what worked for them which was to use mapbox-gl 1.13.0 . I tried it and it works.

`npm uninstall mapbox-gl`

`npm i mapbox-gl@1.13.0`

Leave the other configurations the same and it should work.

Comment: Your proposed solution to downgrade `mapbox-gl@1.13` solved the issue for me. Would you mind to extract that info into an answer? (You can answer your own question and even accept the answer.) It is pretty easy to overlook the edit. Thanks!

Comment: Sure will do. Glad you got it to finally work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason mapbox-gl 2.0 doesn't work properly. Someone else had the same issue and suggested what worked for them which was to use mapbox-gl 1.13.0 . I tried it and it works.

`npm uninstall mapbox-gl`

`npm i mapbox-gl@1.13.0`

Remember to use the following code in `gatsby-node.js` :

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /@mapbox|mapbox-gl/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, I was able to make it work w/ mapbox v2 in Gatsby 2 with `import mapboxgl from "!mapbox-gl";` as described in mapboxgl docs https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#transpiling-v2

Answer (score 0):

Among the configuration, you are missing some stuff, because in the guide, there is a class-based component and you are using a functional one, change it to:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";

const styles = {
  width: "220px",
  height: '130px',
  margin: '2em 0'
};


const Map = () => {


  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const mapContainer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {

    mapboxgl.accessToken = process.env.MY_KEY
    const initializeMap = ({ setMap, mapContainer }) => {
      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: mapContainer.current,
        style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11", 
        center: [-6.2603, 53.3498],
        zoom: 9
      });

      map.on("load", () => {
        setMap(map);
        map.resize();
      });
       new mapboxgl.Marker({color:'#1E3873'}).setLngLat([-6.2603, 53.3498]).addTo(map)

    };

    if (!map) initializeMap({ setMap, mapContainer });

   return () => {
      map.remove()
   }
  }, []);


  return <div ref={mapContainer} style={styles} />;



};

export default Map;
```

Notice the `ref` and the map initializer. I think that it's not properly set when running a `gatsby build` and, since you have passing it as a reference in `el => (mapContainer.current = el)` it's not being rehydrated. React guides should differ a little bit when dealing with Gatsby due to their SSR (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering).

Regarding the webpack issue.

Try:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /mapbox-gl/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Or:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /@mapbox/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Or ignoring both with:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === "build-html") {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /@mapbox/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
          {
            test: /mapbox-gl/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    })
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the testing rule is a regular expression (that's why is written between slashes) that should match a folder inside `node_modules` so it should be an exact path.

This is a [needed workaround for every dependency that uses `window`, or other global objects as a dev-dependency for themselves](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/). This is because, the interpreter when running `gatsby develop` is the browser (browser-side rendering), where there's a `window` available and while running `gatsby build`, the code is compiled in the server (Node), where there isn't a `window` obviously.

The snippet above adds a `null` loader during the webpack's transpilation, or in other words, forces webpack to ignore the module to avoid a code-breaking.

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately, I even tried putting `actions.setWebPackConfig` twice with each value in each function, but it still refuses to work.

Comment: It should be defined once only. However, try to look for the Mapbox library in your `node_modules` to check the naming. Sometimes, when ignoring a module appears a new error for a new dependency (dependant) so it may help you get the correct ignore value.

Comment: I did the ‘node modules’ search and there are only 2 map box folders. One is @mapbox and the other is mapbox-gl. I’ve tried putting them in separately and as an ‘or’ regex pattern /@mapbox|mapbox-gl/ but I still get the issue.

Comment: Can you define "still not working"? Is there exactly the same error? a new one?

Comment: Yes sorry, the issue is still exactly the same. The build is fine and runs successfully, site loads up, everything works fine except the map displaying the map. It’s still as the same as the picture I put in my original post.

Comment: I've updated the original post so you can check the component, and added images of dev mode and once it has been built using `gatsby build`

Comment: Check the updated answer and play a little bit with the `refs`, I think your issue comes from there.

Comment: I tried changing the refs but get exactly the same issue. I found a gatsby-mapbox-starter on GitHub and tried `gatsby develop` `gatsby build` and `gatsby serve` and they all worked fine and the map rendered properly.

I tried to use that code in my site but it just refuses to work no matter what.

Comment: This is the starter https://github.com/brendan-ward/gatsby-starter-mapbox .

Comment: Based on that code, I've updated the answer removing the dependencies for the `useEffect` and I've added an unmount function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's still exactly the same. No effect whatsoever.